# Does firebase count engagement time for android intent?

Tags: firebase, flutter, android-intent, firebase-analytics, model-viewer

I have an AR app built in flutter and I am using [github.com/drydart/model_viewer.dart](https://github.com/drydart/model_viewer.dart) to take care of the AR part.

The problem is that model_viewer displays AR using sceneviewer using android intent. My question is two-fold:

1. Does firebase analytics count time spent in sceneviewer in average engagement time of my app?
2. If not, how Can I include it?